# MySQL on Linux, running on Windows 10, gives error "Failed to connect to bus"

Tags: mysql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I’m trying to run MySQL on Linux which is running on Windows 10 but I’m getting an error:

```
Failed to connect to bus: host is down on linux
```

Comment: You might want to provide a bit more detail.  I assume you're using WSL or WSL2 (which?).  What distribution?  How are you attempting to start mysql?  What commands you ran?  And  the _exact_ output you got back.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a few assumptions here that you don't state in your question, but we've [seen this enough](https://askubuntu.com/q/1379425/1165986) to know what you're probably running into here.

You seem to be attempting to use something like:

```
sudo systemctl start mysqld
```

This will not work out-of-the-box because Systemd is not enabled on WSL.  Up until fairly recently, it wasn't available at all, apart from some creative "hacks."

If you are running a distribution (such as Ubuntu) that still provides the `init.d` script, your best best is to use it instead:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Alternatively, you can enable enable Systemd as discussed in [my Ask Ubuntu answer to that question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379567/1165986) and you should be able to start MySQL using the "normal" methods.